# Installing nginx as a ruby gem vs using apt-get

Tags: ruby, nginx, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I'm new to running a Linux server and slowly getting up to speed with things.

I have already installed nginx via the apt-get function, although I'm following a tutorial which recommends installing it as a ruby gem instead.

Is there any difference in the functionality/limitations to installing it as a gem than by using apt-get? - I'm worried that it won't work for non-ruby applications if it is gem installed?

Comment: Does the tutorial recommends installing nginx as a gem? Could you link to it? I don't think that is common. What it is common is to install the "app server" (e.g. thin/unicorn/webrick) as a gem, though.

Comment: sure: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

From memory, it was far far quicker and easier to install via apt-get than as a gem

Comment: I see. I didn't know there was a gem to automate some of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference in the functionality/limitations to installing it as a gem than by using apt-get? - I'm worried that it won't work for non-ruby applications if it is gem installed?

There aren't any limitations on the version of Nginx that Passenger installs for you. You should be able to use it with other languages as you normally would (providing you know how to configure Nginx.) I was able to use it to connect to both Ruby and Node.js sites with no problems.

The people at Phusion have a nice page explaining why they are forced to provide their own version of Nginx (rather than using the standalone one) and it comes down to the fact that Nginx does not allow to be extended at runtime. Extensions like Passenger must be compiled into it. See this page for more information on it: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Why-can%27t-Phusion-Passenger-extend-my-existing-Nginx%3F

(Note: When I tested this I used the installation instructions from the Phusion web site https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu , rather than the gem that is indicated in your tutorial, but I suspect they are both equivalent.)

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this too. Where I am recommended to use one package manager over the other. I would question the age of the tutorial first, if it is not relatively recent you may want to consider if the information is no longer up to date. The libraries installed with that method may not be up to date.

However, if you intend to follow through with the tutorial you may end up needing it installed as the tutorial describes.

The difference is that one may not have all the libraries that are required or may not have the most up to date version. One tool could be buggy, I don't think this is the case in your situation but it is in Macports v.s Homebrew in my opinion. It might install to a different directory based on what install method you use, if you use a method off the web and then go back to the tutorial it could be installed to a different location then your tutorial expects.

If you have to follow the tutorial then I would all the way through, but if you don't need to use the preferred method that the program/library maintainers recommend. If the tutorial is out of date you could try to find an up to date tutorial.

good luck!